# I am having trouble with the await returns value. Here is detail: when I call the HTTPGET request, I get the error below here. Thank you in advance

Tags: c#, asp.net

1. **When I try**

   ```
    var treeOpcUa = await tree.ConvertModel(serverUrl, decodedNodeId);
   ```
2. **Code Behind** *And the lines 60 and 90 are commented with: //This is where the bug*

   ```
      public async Task<TreeOpcUa<ModelOfNode>> ConvertModel(string serverUrl, string decodedNodeId)
    {
        var sourceNode = await _uaClient.ReadNodeAsync(serverUrl, decodedNodeId);
        TreeOpcUa<ModelOfNode> treeOpcUa = new TreeOpcUa<ModelOfNode>();
        treeOpcUa.Root = new TreeNode<ModelOfNode>()
        {
            Data = new ModelOfNode()
            {
                NodeId = decodedNodeId,
                Name = sourceNode.DisplayName.Text.ToString(),
                Type = (sourceNode.NodeClass == NodeClass.Object) ? (await _uaClient.IsFolderTypeAsync(serverUrl, decodedNodeId) ? "folder" : "object") : "variable"
            },
            Parent = null
        };
        var refDescriptions = await _uaClient.BrowseAsync(serverUrl, decodedNodeId);
        if (refDescriptions.Count() != 0) treeOpcUa.Root.Data.Relationship = "HasComponent";
        else treeOpcUa.Root.Data.Relationship = "NoComponent";
        treeOpcUa.Root.ChildrenNode = new List<TreeNode<ModelOfNode>>();
        int temp = 0;
        treeOpcUa.Root.ChildrenNode = await LoopTask(serverUrl, decodedNodeId, treeOpcUa.Root);
        return treeOpcUa;
    }

    public async Task<List<TreeNode<ModelOfNode>>> LoopTask(string serverUrl, string decodedNodeId, TreeNode<ModelOfNode> parentNode)
    {

        var refDescriptions = await _uaClient.BrowseAsync(serverUrl, decodedNodeId);
        int temp = 0;
        if (refDescriptions.Count() != 0)
            foreach (var rd in refDescriptions)
            {
                var treeNode = new TreeNode<ModelOfNode>();
                var refTypeNode = await _uaClient.ReadNodeAsync(serverUrl, rd.ReferenceTypeId);
                switch (rd.NodeClass)
                {
                    case NodeClass.Variable:
                        {
                            var workNode = await _uaClient.ReadNodeAsync(serverUrl, rd.PlatformNodeId);
                            var varNode = (VariableNode)workNode;
                            var uaValue = await _uaClient.ReadUaValueAsync(serverUrl, varNode);
                            treeNode.Parent = parentNode;
                            treeNode.Data = new ModelOfNode()//This is where the bug appear
                            {
                                NodeId = rd.PlatformNodeId,
                                Type = "variable",
                                Name = rd.DisplayName.ToString(),
                                Value = (uaValue != null) ? (double)uaValue.Value : null,
                                ValueSchemaType = uaValue.Schema.ToString(),
                                Status = uaValue.StatusCode?.ToString() ?? "",
                                DeadBand = await _uaClient.GetDeadBandAsync(serverUrl, varNode),
                                MinimumSamplingInterval = varNode.MinimumSamplingInterval,
                                Relationship = refTypeNode.DisplayName.Text
                            };
                            parentNode.ChildrenNode.Add(treeNode);
                            break;
                        }
                    case NodeClass.Method:
                        temp++;
                        break;
                    case NodeClass.Object:
                        treeNode.Parent = parentNode;
                        treeNode.Data = new ModelOfNode()
                        {
                            NodeId = rd.PlatformNodeId,
                            Name = rd.DisplayName.ToString(),
                            Type = await _uaClient.IsFolderTypeAsync(serverUrl, rd.PlatformNodeId)
                            ? "folder"
                            : "object"
                        };
                        parentNode.ChildrenNode.Add(treeNode);
                        parentNode.ChildrenNode[temp].ChildrenNode = new List<TreeNode<ModelOfNode>>();
                        parentNode.ChildrenNode[temp].ChildrenNode = await LoopTask(serverUrl, rd.PlatformNodeId.ToString(), parentNode.ChildrenNode[temp]);//This is where the bug appear
                        temp++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
        return parentNode.ChildrenNode;
    }
   ```
3. **The error is this:**

> *System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
> at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
> at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)
> at System.Convert.ToDouble(Object value, IFormatProvider provider)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.op_Explicit(JToken value)
> at API.Extensions.ConvertJsonObjectToModel.LoopTask(String serverUrl, String decodedNodeId, TreeNode parentNode) in E:\NckhOpcUaApi\API\Extensions\ConvertJsonObjectToModel.cs:line 60
> at API.Extensions.ConvertJsonObjectToModel.LoopTask(String serverUrl, String decodedNodeId, TreeNode parentNode) in E:\NckhOpcUaApi\API\Extensions\ConvertJsonObjectToModel.cs:line 90
> at API.Extensions.ConvertJsonObjectToModel.LoopTask(String serverUrl, String decodedNodeId, TreeNode parentNode) in E:\NckhOpcUaApi\API\Extensions\ConvertJsonObjectToModel.cs:line 90
> at API.Extensions.ConvertJsonObjectToModel.LoopTask(String serverUrl, String decodedNodeId, TreeNode parentNode) in E:\NckhOpcUaApi\API\Extensions\ConvertJsonObjectToModel.cs:line 90
> at API.Controllers.OpcUaController.GetExpandNodes(String node_id) in E:\NckhOpcUaApi\API\Controllers\OpcUaController.cs:line 159
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)*

Comment: According to the exception it's breaking when trying to convert to a double. From what I can see that looks like it might be at the point your casting the uaValue.Value. I would check that value first.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have solved the problem according to ur suggestion.